# How to remove htmlentities() values from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

Long before I knew anything - not that I know much even now - I desgined a web app in php which inserted data in my mysql database after running the values through `htmlentities()`. I eventually came to my senses and removed this step and stuck it in the output rather than input and went on my merry way.

However I've since had to revisit some of this old data and unfortunately I have an issue, when it's displayed on the screen I'm getting values displayed which are effectively htmlentitied twice.

So,  is there a mysql or phpmyadmin way of changing all the older, affected rows back into their relevant characters or will I have to write a script to read each row, decode and update all 17 million rows in 12 tables?

EDIT:

Thanks for the help everyone, I wrote my own answer down below with some code in, it's not pretty but it worked on the test data earlier so barring someone pointing out a glaring error in my code while I'm in bed I'll be running it on a backup DB tomorrow and then on the live one if that works out alright.

Comment: What's wrong with HTML entities? They're definitely the way to go especially for non-English languages...

Comment: Familiar problem, I´m afraid I haven´t solved it yet either...

Comment: @nico there's nothing wrong with html entities, just I'd prefer the data stored as it was entered, it can be run through htmlentities when output. It was a choice I made after having started the site though so needs standardising for all of the rows.

Comment: @Chris saving it in the DB as HTML entities saves you the call to htmlentities every single time you display it. Anyway I don't think there's a shortcut to do it... gotta loop all over the DB.

Comment: Putting HTML-encoded data in the database is insane. There are plenty of times the output is not going to be HTML (eg. mail addresses, URLs to fetch, data to throw out into some CSV or a PDF, whatever); further, keeping encoded data in the database breaks the ability to use database-level string processing functions, including various matching/indexing. +1 to the OP for recognising the wrongness! Data should be kept in its raw form and escaped for a particular context (such as HTML) only when being inserted into that context.

Comment: note: also, `htmlspecialchars()` should be used in preference to `htmlentities()` in most situations. `htmlentities()` encodes all non-ASCII characters to HTML-specific entity references, which is usually unnecessary, and it defaults to treating non-ASCII bytes as ISO-8859-1, which will mangle your characters if you're using another encoding such as UTF-8 (and these days, you should be using UTF-8 for everything). `htmlspecialchars()` is a better bet as it only escapes the few characters that really need it, leaving non-ASCII characters alone and also generating plain-XML-compatible output.

Comment: @bobince yeah I considered the differences between `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()` when I wrote the code but I think I'd just read some scary stuff on xss at the time so I settled on `htmlentities()` and being the nervous nelly I was I've not gone back and altered anything. I was having some issues with some characters turning up with an Á before them but I specified UTF-8 when encoding and that cleared that issue up and I've had no other problems.

Comment: Bah, depends on the situations. I had cases where the output was pretty much always HTML and saving data in the DB as HTML entities saved me lots of times and headheaches. It's not true you can't index and search with it, just use entities in the search string too. It does work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using this, not pretty, but I'm tired, it's 2am and it did its job! (Edit: on test data)

```
$tables = array('users', 'users_more', 'users_extra', 'forum_posts', 'posts_edits', 'forum_threads', 'orders', 'product_comments', 'products', 'favourites', 'blocked', 'notes');
foreach($tables as $table)
    {       
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE data_date_ts < '{$encode_cutoff}'";
        $rows = $database->query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows))
            {
                $new = array();
                foreach($row as $key => $data)
                    {
                        $new[$key] = $database->escape_value(html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                    }
                array_shift($new);
                $new_string = "";
                $i = 0;
                foreach($new as $new_key => $new_data)
                    {
                        if($i > 0) { $new_string.= ", "; }
                        $new_string.= $new_key . "='" . $new_data . "'";
                        $i++;
                    }
                $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET " . $new_string . " WHERE id='" . $row['id'] . "'";
                $database->query($sql);
                // plus some code to check that all out
            }
    }
```

Comment: In **MySQL** you can generate a list of **tables** using `SHOW TABLES;` and in **PostgreSQL** generate a list of **tables** using `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') ORDER BY table_name ASC;` if you wish to make the script a bit more dynamic.

Answer (score 4):

Since PHP was the method of encoding, you'll want to use it to decode. You can use [html_entity_decode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to convert them back to their original characters. Gotta loop!

Just be careful not to decode rows that don't need it. Not sure how you'll determine that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the use of the function and if I have to update each row I'll be using it, but I wanted to know if there was a shorter way of doing it in mysql or phpmyadmin, ie a mass update on the affected rows. Some obscure function they hid away from me.

Comment: @webbie as for your edited point, yeah I'm lucky, I have the old backups of the source I wrote and the log files so I know precisely when the code was altered, and noseying around at the rows in the DB around that time confirm it too.

Comment: Whew. Good thing you did that!

Answer (score 2):

I think writing a php script is good thing to do in this situation. You can use, as Dave said, the html_entity_decode() function to convert your texts back.

Try your script on a table with few entries first. This will make you save a lot of testing time. Of course, remember to backup your table(s) before running the php script.

I'm afraid there is no shorter possibility. The computation for millions of rows remains quite expensive, no matter how you convert the datasets back. So go for a php script... it's the easiest way

Comment: Yeah it's what I suspected, however I'd been hoping it's the sort of helpful function phpmyadmin might have hidden away somewhere, rather than having to do it myself. At least if I write it I can share it I guess.

Comment: I see... What I wanted to say is that even if phpMyAdmin had such a function (it may have), it would just execute a mysql query via php. You wouldn't save anything in terms of execution time and/or resources. But I think writing a script shouldn't be that hard in this case and you will have fine datasets :)

Answer (score 2):

This is my bullet proof version. It iterates over all Tables and String columns in a database, determines primary key(s) and performs updates.

It is intended to run the php-file from command line to get progress information.

```
<?php
$DBC = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "dbpass", "dbname");
$DBC->set_charset("utf8");

$tables = $DBC->query("SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type='BASE TABLE'");
while($table = $tables->fetch_array()) {
    $table = $table[0];
    $columns = $DBC->query("DESCRIBE `{$table}`");
    $textFields = array();
    $primaryKeys = array();
    while($column = $columns->fetch_assoc()) {
        // check for char, varchar, text, mediumtext and so on
        if ($column["Key"] == "PRI") {
            $primaryKeys[] = $column['Field'];
        } else if (strpos( $column["Type"], "char") !== false || strpos($column["Type"], "text") !== false ) {
            $textFields[] = $column['Field'];
        }
    }
    if (!count($primaryKeys)) {
        echo "Cannot convert table without primary key: '$table'\n";
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($textFields as $textField) {
        $sql = "SELECT `".implode("`,`", $primaryKeys)."`,`$textField` from `$table` WHERE `$textField` like '%&%'";
        $candidates = $DBC->query($sql);
        $tmp = $DBC->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
        $rowCount = $tmp->fetch_array()[0];
        $tmp->free();
        echo "Updating $rowCount in $table.$textField\n";
        $count=0;
        while($candidate = $candidates->fetch_assoc()) {
            $oldValue = $candidate[$textField];
            $newValue = html_entity_decode($candidate[$textField], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8');
            if ($oldValue != $newValue) {
                $sql = "UPDATE `$table` SET `$textField` = '"
                    . $DBC->real_escape_string($newValue)
                    . "' WHERE ";
                foreach ($primaryKeys as $pk) {
                    $sql .= "`$pk` = '" . $DBC->real_escape_string($candidate[$pk]) . "' AND ";
                }
                $sql .= "1";
                $DBC->query($sql);
            }
            $count++;
            echo "$count / $rowCount\r";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

cheers
Roland

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit kludgy but I think the mass update is the only way to go...

```
$Query = "SELECT row_id, html_entitied_column FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($Query, $connection);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $updatedValue = html_entity_decode($row['html_entitied_column']);
    $Query = "UPDATE table SET html_entitied_column = '" . $updatedValue . "' ";
    $Query .= "WHERE row_id = " . $row['row_id'];
    mysql_query($Query, $connection);
}
```

This is simplified, no error handling etc.
Not sure what the processing time would be on millions of rows so you might need to break it up into chunks to avoid script timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Since I had multiple clients running the application in production, I wanted to avoid running a PHP script to clean the database for every one of them.

I came up with a solution that is far from perfect, but does the job painlessly.

1. Track all the spots in your code where you use htmlentities() before inserting data, and remove that.
2. Change your "display data as HTML" method to something like this :

   return html_entity_decode(htmlentities($chaine, ENT_NOQUOTES), ENT_NOQUOTES);

The undo-redo process is kind of ridiculous, but it does the job. And your database will slowly clean itself everytime users update the incorrect data.